# Error : No method available to convert ProgID to CLSID

Tags: vb.net, dcom, opc, clsid, progid

I am using **OPC Labs QuickOPC 5.31** in VB.NET application to read the OPC tags from the **Top server**. The application and the Top Server are located in different machine. **DCOM** is configured in both machine.

I have used the **ProgID** (*SWToolbox.TOPServer.V5*) to connect the Top server.

```
EasyDAClient.ReadItemValue("Machine-PC", "SWToolbox.TOPServer.V5", "TagName")
```

It was working fine for past 3 months, now the application throws the errror.

> **Error**    : No method available to convert ProgID to CLSID.
>     **ErrorCode**: -1073442759

If I change the **ProgID**(*SWToolbox.TOPServer.V5*) to **ClassId** (*{r466fbf7-c92d-341d-84be-3476123deccd68}*) to connect the TOPserver, it works fine.

```
EasyDAClient.ReadItemValue("Machine-PC", "{680dfbf7-c92d-484d-84be-
                                  06dc3deccd68}", "TagName")
```

Another OPC client application running on the same machine as Top server located, it uses **ProgID** (*SWToolbox.TOPServer.V5*) to connect the Top server, it also working fine.

The error is only from the remote OPC client applications which are using the **ProgID** to connect the **TOPServer**.

Let me know the reason for the error?

Comment: Most likely is that the ProgId disappeared from the registry.  Use Regedit.exe on the good machine to have a look, `HKCR\SWToolbox.TOPServer.V5\CLSID` registry key.  Contact the vendor for support if that guess was not accurate.

Comment: @Hans Passant :  I have checked the registery. `HKCR\SWToolbox.TOPServer.V5\CLSID` is available.